# AngularJS/PHP form inside ng-repeat : how to get specific data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, post, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form which is composed of an ng-repeat (for each demand).
The user will be able to edit the "date réalisation" or the "motif refus" inside this ng-repeat, and will click on the button submit "Valider la modification", still inside this ng-repeat (to edit the demand in demands).

Here is the code :

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="gestDemInstallController">
<h1 class="text-center">{{ soustitre }}</h1>

<p>{{presentation}}</p>


      <!--une ligne pour chaque demande
      utilisation de getDataDemandesInstall.php
      et de getDataDemandesInstallApplis.php
      -->

      <form> 
      {{ reussite }}<!-- indique un msg au clic du gestionnaire -->

      <br><!-- on affiche chaque demande d'installation -->
      <div ng-repeat="dem in demandesInstallations" class="tableau">
          <br>
          <label>ID :</label>
          {{dem.id}}

          <br>
          <label>Ordinateur :</label>
          {{dem.nomPC}}

          <br>
          <label>Date demande :</label>
          {{dem.dateDemande}}

          <br>
          <label>Date réalisation :</label>
          <input ng-model="date_real" type="date" value="{{dem.dateRealisation}}" class="form-control input-normal bouton">
          Date enregistrée: {{dem.dateRealisation}}

          <br><br>
          <label>Motif refus :</label>
          <input ng-model="motif_refus" type="text" value="{{dem.motifRefus}}" class="form-control input-normal bouton">

          <br>
          <label>Unité :</label>
          {{dem.unite}}

          <br>
          <label>Demandeur :</label>
          {{dem.demandeur}}


          <br>
          <!--boucle ng-repeat affichant chaque appli et profil choisi-->
          <div ng-repeat="a in demandesInstallApplis">
            <label><i>Applications demandées</i></label><br>

            <label>Nom application :</label>
            {{a.nom}}

            <br>
            <label>Profil demandé :</label>
            {{}}
          </div><!--fin ligne les applications-->


          <input ng-model="btn{{dem.id}}" ng-click="checkGestDemInstall()" type="button" value="Valider la modification" class="form-control">

      </div><!--fin de la demande, fin du ng-repeat-->

      </form>
```

And here is the Controller (AngularJS)

```
//----RECUPERATION DES DONNEES : METHODE POST---------//
//----------------------------------------------------//

$scope.checkGestDemInstall = function(){
    //on valide les données entrées
    //on peut ensuite les envoyer au script PHP
    //en utilisant la méthode HTTP Post

    var error=0;

    /*---- Le mot de passe est vérifié --*/

    //si pas d'erreur (ni d'erreur mdp ni d'erreur id/mail)
    if (error === 0) {
        //on lance la méthode POST de la requête HTTP
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/sio2/projets/gedeon_php/pages/postGestDemInstall.php",
            data: {
                //celui qui a été cliqué
                date_real: $scope.date_real,
                motif_refus: $scope.motif_refus
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
        /* Check whether the HTTP Request is Successfull or not. */
        request.success(function (data) {
            $scope.reussite = "Données bien envoyées : "+data +" (information réceptionnée de PHP)";
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.reussite = "Vous avez mal rempli le formulaire. Erreur de type : " + error;
    }

}; //fin fonction checkGestDemInstall()
```

As you can see in my Controller, I would like to get my data, I mean the dem.date_real and the dem.motif_refus, whereas I have the same ng-model for each input... Indeed I have several inputs (one by ng-repeat) and I don't really know how to get data from the "date_real" edited and the "motif refus" edited.

Thanks for any advices !

////////////////////
**Thanks to your advice I now have these codes but still with some errors :**
**ERROR 1 :** $parse:syntax

**ERROR 2 :** ngRepeat:dupes

here inside my ng-repeat dem in demands :

```
<label>Date réalisation :</label>
        <input ng-model="dem.dateRealisation" type="text" value="{{dem.dateRealisation}}" class="form-control input-normal bouton">
        Date enregistrée: {{dem.dateRealisation}}

        <br><br>
        <label>Motif refus :</label>
        <input ng-model="dem.motifRefus" type="text" value="{{dem.motifRefus}}" class="form-control input-normal bouton">
```

and here in my Controller :

```
data: {
                    //celui qui a été cliqué
                    date_real: $scope.dateRealisation, //= new Date(dateRealisation),//error ngModel:datefmt
                    motif_refus: $scope.motifRefus
                },
```

And then here to POST my data, I want to check by echoing it in PHP as I usually do before doing an insert...

```
    include('../bdd/conn.php');

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$date_real = $request->dateRealisation;
@$motif_refus = $request->motifRefus;


echo 'date real : '. $date_real . ' motif refus : '. $motif_refus;
```

I like everything to be understandable so I made a small scheme to explain :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Did you use google translate? Please explain your problem. So we can help ya. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the last explanation, sorry if that was confused, I started recently learning AngularJS ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, change your ng-model to `dem.dateRealisation` and `dem.motifRefus` instead of `date_real` and `motif_refus`. If you use the variables defined on the scope then for every demand that you change the dates for it will update these variables, only ever returning one value for each.

If you want the data you are sending in your Post request to contain the dates for every demand, then you'll have to send a different object. You could send `demandesInstallations` and then change how this data object is handled

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I still have some errors and perhaps I have not explained very well my pb also ! So in fact if the user wants to modifiy 1 date only, or 1 motif_refus, he will be able to click on The button corresponding to these two inputs (I mean in the same repetition). But the user will never edit all dates in 1 time. So I updated my question (my method POST still doesn't work for the moment), I still can't get my data from this ng-repeat I think because of my syntax

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question. Try changing your submit button to `<input ng-model="btn{{dem.id}}" ng-click="checkGestDemInstall(dem)" type="button" value="Valider la modification" class="form-control">` and then change your checkGestDemInstall function to accept a dem object. Then change `date_real: dem.dateRealisation` and `motif_refus: dem.motifRefus` in the data object you're sending

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it doesn't make anything happen while clicking on the button where I put exactly what you told. I now have <input ng-model="dem.dateRealisation" ...

and same for motif refus : <input ng-model="dem.motifRefus" ...

and in my controller : ... = function(dem){ ...
data: {
                    date_real: $scope.dem.dateRealisation
                    motif_refus: $scope.dem.motifRefus

Comment: And I am not really sure to understand what I put in this data { ... } of my function now taking the object dem as a parameter...
I mean, where did I say the programm : the user clicked on That button ?
Thank you very much for your explanations and help ! :)

Comment: You wouldn't need to put $scope in your data object as you are passing in the `dem` object. So `data: { date_real: dem.dateRealisation, motif_refus: dem.motifRefus}`

Comment: I had tried this too, wasn't sure of my $scope... Indeed still the same 2 errors (Error: [$parse:syntax], and Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]) and result : nothing happens on the click... I am trying some other things but haven't met this pb anywhere else so I don't really know how to make my program understand I click on this specific button like I would do in simple JS with a specific id for my btn and the two inputs to edit...